# Java.io.*, What does it do exactly?

Tags: java

Nooby question but what is java.io.* in java?  More specifically the "import java.io.*;
that you put on your java source file.

What I know about it is that it's a class that you can import into your java source file that's already premade by java.  And a class, from my understanding is an instance of an object, for example, a red bike is a class of the bicycle family and a blue bike is another class of the bicycle family.  I'm struggling to find out what java.io* does exactly.  What does it allow me to do?  From my understanding the * signals that it will take all the library that falls under the java.io tree

Thanks

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but close enough as it explains what the wild-card in the import does.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html